# VSCode python editor can't use function "Format On Type"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, format

In my limited experience with using VSCode. My VSCode python editor can't use function "Format on Type: Control the editor to automatically format a line after you type it". I've turned this on in settings but it's not working while my R editor can work, just python editor can't.

I don't know why. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you install the python extension?

Comment: Yes,I've alredy installed python extension and it can run python code in VSCode

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we use autopep8 or black to format Python files.

However, the format on type is not support via black or autopep8.

You can install [Black Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.black-formatter) or [autopep8](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.autopep8) extension and add the following settings.

**Black Formatter**

```
  "[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  }
```

**autopep8**

```
  "[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.autopep8",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  }
```

Comment: Ok, does that mean we can't use Format on type on Python?

Comment: Thank you for your guidance, I understand what you mean. However, when I followed the steps to install the plugin and set it up, the Python code can be automatically formatted after pressing "Ctrl+s" to auto-save, but it still does not automatically format after using the "Enter" key to start a new line. It seems that "editor.formatOnType": true is not working. Below is my settings.json: 
'''
"[python]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter", "editor.formatOnSave": true, 
"editor.formatOnType": true
 }
‘'’

Comment: I'm sorry I mistook the information and currently do not support formatOnType. The relevant function request has been raised in Github, and currently all that can be done is to manually save multiple times for formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I have added just path to black which is being in my env

```
"[python]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-python.black-formatter",
    "black-formatter.path": "./env-a6mpcL/bin/black"
  }
```